# Bootstrap: "success", "warning" and "danger" transparent issue

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my problem. As you can see [here](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/pages/index.html) they have used `panel panel-primary`, `panel panel-green`, `panel panel-yellow` and `panel panel-red` for the small panel views.

When I use `panel panel-primary` it is working just fine. But when I use other options, I get weird paled transparent colors. I tried `panel panel-warning`, `panel panel-success` and `panel panel-danger` as well but still the same. Only primary works. Any ideas?

I have 4 of these, exactly same with different text.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats" style="font-size:50px;"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
          <div class=></div>
          <div><h3>Statistics</h3></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#">
    <div class="panel-footer">
      <span class="pull-left">Show statistics</span>
      <span class="pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i></span>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have four small panels as in the link above. All of them are inside the same `<div>` element.

Comment: @RyanMcDonough I added code snippet

Answer (score 0):

The other panels except the primary one are not from bootstrap's css. I think they are user written.
Create your own class in your css file.
For example:

```css
.panel-red{
background-color:#D9534F;
}
```

here is a jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/borka/khaunb3q/